# HQL Object Named Parameters

Tags: hql

I was wondering if it is possible to retrieve a specific column from an object named parameter in HQL.

Example

```
public class Product
{
    private int id;
    private Supplier supplier;

    private String name;
    private String description;
    private double price;

    public Product()
    {
        super();
    }

    public Product(String name, String description, double price)
    {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getDescription()
    {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description)
    {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public int getId()
    {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Supplier getSupplier()
    {
        return supplier;
    }
    public void setSupplier(Supplier supplier)
    {
        this.supplier = supplier;
    }

    public double getPrice()
    {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(double price)
    {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

as you can see I created the product and it has a supplier object within it.
So when I do HQL and call

```
String hql = "from Product as product where product.supplier=:supplier";
        Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
        query.setEntity("supplier",supplier);
        List results = query.list();
        displayProductsList(results);
```

but is it possible to just get product's supplier's name?
and not just the whole supplier?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Would you like to select only the supplier's name? Or would you like to find all products by supplier name? Or would you like to select products but only have their supplier's name populated rather than all its attributes, i.e. get all the product fields + the supplier name of the product?

Comment: Trying to select the supplier's name so it would be product.supplier.name

Comment: If you just want the supplier names, then use select supplier.name from Supplier supplier. Why use the Product entity if all you're interested into is the suppliers?

Comment: because I want the products from a specific supplier name.

Comment: So, you don't want to select the supplier's name. You want to select products. Which products do you want to select? Those of a supplier with a given name?

Comment: Yup! but I didn't know if you can actually retrieve a specific column from supplier name since it's an entity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just don't pass a Supplier instance to your query, but pass the supplier's name directly:

```
String hql = "from Product as product where product.supplier.name = :supplierName";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setString("supplierName", supplier.getName());
List results = query.list();
displayProductsList(results);
```

Comment: Hmmm interesting I didn't think of that, but I'm still learning! haha

Comment: @jbnizet can you please tell me what this is `=:` or what is it called in HQL?

Comment: = is the equal sign, just like in SQL. `:supplierName` defines a named parameter for the query.