# Hibernate pass POJO object as parameter, and use it's properties. Is it possible?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I tried to pass POJO as hibernate parameter, but it crashes with Exception, I actually not understand. I tried to find why and not get anything clear. Is it possible to use POJO fields, in where condition?

Here query with its parameter description:

```
@Query("select jc "
        + "from JobChron jc "
        + "where "
        + "jc.state=:catalogPage.state and "
        + "jc.city=:catalogPage.city and "
        + "jc.vertical=:catalogPage.vertical "
        )
LinkedList<JobChron> selectOpen(
        @Param("catalogPage") CatalogPage catalogPage);
```

The root exception I see is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.lookupProperty(HqlSqlWalker.java:598)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.addrExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4980)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.expr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1263)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.exprOrSubquery(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4686)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.comparisonExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4159)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2104)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2029)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2029)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.whereClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:796)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:597)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:249)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1836)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:344)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy67.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:86)
    ... 118 more
```

Comment: take a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbrg.html) , the `:` identifiers are being used like formatting a string and append the values to the corresponding places #1 , #2 ..etc. It could be done if you were trying to join those 2 tables like : `"select jc 
        from JobChron jc ,CatalogPage catalogPage
        where 
        jc.state=catalogPage.state and 
        jc.city=catalogPage.city and 
        jc.vertical=catalogPage.vertical and catalogPage.id= :id"`

Comment: I'm not sure this somehow helps. First of all I use HQL (Hibernate query language), while your reference JavaEE ... i do not know for sure is this still relevant. Please confirm this. The second issue here is CatalogPage object is not a persisted entity. It is POJO and for now it only stored in RAM of my application, so cannot call it from database table

Comment: ............................no comments , check [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html) also , or better for your understanding check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011980/hql-object-named-parameters)

Comment: if you still want to pass the whole object , then you can bind the query with a property entity , check mkyong's [solution](https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-parameter-binding-examples/) at example 3 with the `setProperty()` method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case you are using *@org.springframework.data.repository.query.Query* and *@Param* from Spring Data: it is not implemented.

Your parameter name "*catalogPage*" and parameter value *catalogPage* eventually go as is to *org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.bindValue(catalogPage)* -> *org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter("catalogPage", catalogPage)* which eventually goes to simple text replacement in *AbstractQueryImpl.expandParameterList(...)*. No parameter pre-processing that support the required feature.

**Update: there is a way to do this, via Spring EL!**
See https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions

Comment: So As I understand I have to pass each String object property as parameter, instead of passing POJO itself.

Comment: I did not know this before you asked! Yes, it is possible!