# Parameter not bound in Hibernate Query

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I tried to make a query withSpring data for updating an entry by id and I tried a lot options but still I can't get rid of this:

```
Named parameter not bound : table.eventDate
```

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = "update Table_name u set u.id = :table.id, u.event_date = :table.eventDate, u.client_id = :table.clientId, u.status = :table.status, u.status_date = :table.statusDate, u.creation_date = :table.creationDate, u.last_update_date = :table.lastUpdateDate where u.id = :table.id",
    nativeQuery = true)
void updateEntity(@Param("table") Table table);
```

How should I write the query in order to get rid of this?

I tried a lot of posibilities online to write the query but nothing worked.

Comment: Can you show `Table` class

Comment: Does this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/38455540/1460591?

Answer (score -1):

Correct native query statement:

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = "update Table_name u set u.id = :table.id, u.event_date = :table.event_date, u.client_id = :table.client_id, u.status = :table.status, u.status_date = :table.status_date, u.creation_date = :table.creation_date, u.last_update_date = :table.last_update_date where u.id = :table.id",
    nativeQuery = true)
void updateEntity(@Param("table") Table table);
```

Since you're using a native query instead of a JPQL-Query, you have to write :table.event_date instead of :table.eventDate. Same counts for example :table.clientId, it has to be :table.client_id.
Hope it'll work!

Native Queries: Always snake_case instead of camelCase, unless your column names are in camelCase, but I doubt that. :)

Comment: it doesn't work